# #C++ DOTA 2 (Viper) Caculating the time

Tags: c++

I got that problem :
"Viper is being a hero of Dota 2 with special skill that reduce the speed moving of the others approximately 40% in 2 seconds and we coudn't plus all of these together for instance when it was 1s, Viper used this special one and he did again when left 1s. So totally times that the others heros moving slowly is 3(s)"

+Input:
Series of time that Viper used this special skills and stop when it was -1;

+Output:
Totally time that the others heros got !
Another example:

**Input:**

- ### 1.3 3.1 5.7 7.4 11.4 14.0 16.9 17.0 19.0 22.3 22.5 24.5 -1

**Output:**

- ### 19.8

->***My problem is that this code doesn't correct at all cases !***
Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std

int main()
{
  long double a,b,c,h,s=0,luuso[100000];
  int i=0;
  do
  {
   cin>>a;
   luuso[i]=a;
    i++;
  } while(a!=-1);

    h=i-1;
    i=0;
    do {
    if((luuso[i+1]-luuso[i])<2 && (luuso[i+1]-luuso[i])>0)
    {
        s+=luuso[i+1]-luuso[i]+2;
        i+=2;
    }
    else
    {
        s+=2;
        i++;
    }
    } while(i!=h);

    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first step would be giving variables proper names instead of `a`, `b`, `c`...

Comment: Also useful would the use of proper types, such as `std::vector<int> inputs` instead of `int[10000]`.

Comment: I would  fix this problems , but I couldn't correct all of cases which was given by my teacher !